# Getting a segmentation code while running the following code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

please help me out here....my program given below is showing segmentation fault....i have no idea what is wrong with it..

```
Runtime Error: SEG
Description: Segmentation fault
Runtime: 0.1
```

(this is always shown when the program is run.....)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char sent[1000][80],reqd[1000][80],temp[80];
    unsigned int i,j,k=0,l=0,n,num=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin.getline(sent[i],80);
    }
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        for(i=0; i<strlen(sent[j]); i++)
        {
            while(sent[j][i]!=' '&&sent[j][i]!='\0')
            {
                reqd[l][k]=sent[j][i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            reqd[l][k]='\0';
            l++;
            k=0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<=l; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<l-i-1; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(reqd[j],reqd[j+1])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,reqd[j+1]);
                strcpy(reqd[j+1],reqd[j]);
                strcpy(reqd[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    num=l;
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(reqd[i],reqd[i+1])==0)
        {
            reqd[i][0]=' ';
            num--;
        }
    }
    cout<<num<<"\n";
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if(reqd[i][0]!=' ')
        {
            cout<<reqd[i]<<"\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please do help me find the problem....

Comment: What a code-formatting!!

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger It will tell you the line that the fault occurs on and hence may lead us to a solution. **Please format the code so it is readable**

Comment: ya.... i did......my program worked perfectly well in turbo c++...but then i had to make sum changes to it so tht it can be evaluated by g++ compiler......and then it started showing segmentation error.........no idea whats wrong with it....

Comment: Poor quality question - unreadable code due to lack of formatting plus no apparent attempt to debug - voting to close.

Comment: format the code in what way??

Comment: There are tools to tell you where a program is crashing.  Use them.  It's much easier for us to help you if we know where the problem is.  As far as the different compilers go, there is a lot of stuff that the C++ standard doesn't define, and anything goes in those areas.  If you get different results between two compilers, either at least one of them isn't conforming to the standard, or you've done something you shouldn't.

Comment: @Benoit has now kindly formatted the code for you - please try and pay attention to this in future if you want people to be able to read your code

Comment: Hint: the code appears to be crashing in the call to `strcpy` in this line: `strcpy(reqd[j+1],reqd[j]);`

Comment: oh..thank you...will do that....

Comment: there shudnt be any problem in that line..

Comment: If you run the code under a debugger you will see that there *is* a problem in that line (although the actual bugs are probably earlier in the code - this crash is just their manifestation).

Comment: Please don't fool yourself into believing that you're learning C++... and don't pay anyone who claims they're teaching it if that's what you're getting!

Comment: there seems to be a problem because of using unsigned int....why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the crash is this loop:

```
for(i=0; i<=l; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<l-i-1; j++)
```

In the last iteration, `l-i-1` should the value `-1`; however, since these are unsigned, the result wraps round to a very large positive value, and the loop never exits. Instead, it gallops through memory until it reaches an invalid address, and crashes.

Some possible fixes are:

- changing the counters' type to `int`
- changing the loop termination condition to `j+1<l-i`
- looping from 1 while `j<l-i`, and changing the loop to compare `sent[j-1]` to `sent[j]`.

Also, if the initial number you read is supposed to be on a line by itself, then you'll want to call `cin.ignore()` after reading it; otherwise, you'll get an unwanted blank line as your first input.

But if you're going to use C++, I suggest you learn how to use the standard library, in particular classes such as `std::string`, containers such as `std::vector`, and algorithms such as `std::sort`. Messing around with C-style strings and fixed-length buffers is bound to lead to bugs like this.

Something like this would do the same thing with less scope for errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t lines;
    cin >> lines;
    if (!cin.ignore()) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    vector<string> words;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
        string line;
        getline(cin, line);
        istringstream stream(line);
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(stream),
             istream_iterator<string>(),
             back_inserter(words));
    }

    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    words.erase(unique(words.begin(), words.end()), words.end());

    cout << words.size() << '\n';
    copy(words.begin(), words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: will it be ok if i make the i loop as :   (i=0;i<l;i++) so then....i wnt be equal to l ......

Comment: @amritha: Maybe; you'd have to analyse your sorting algorithm to work out whether it will still give the correct results in that case. Unless you really want to learn how to implement bubble-sort (one of the worst sorting algorithms around), I'd just use `std::sort` (or `qsort` if you want to stick with your C-like style).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see a segmentation fault in C/C++ you should think first of pointer issues (or equivalently array issues.)  In this case, I'd be a dollar that you're overrunning the length of your character array, because you are treating it like a string but reading the same size as you hve the string length.  Remember that a C string always has one more byte than the string length, because of the terminator character.

Answer (score 2):

It might be due to `cin.getline(sent[i],80);` where you are not taking into account of the null character.

Comment: `cin.getline(sent[i],79); ` instead

Comment: No, 80 is fine; `getline` reads up to `n-1` characters, and always terminates the string.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix

```
cin >> variable;
```

with

```
cin.getline()
```

cin does not remove new line so it will be read by your getline later on.

instead of

```
cin.getline(sent[i],80);
```

try

```
cin >> sent[i];
```

Comment: actually sent[i] is a string and i initially used gets(sent[i]) for it.....but g++ didnt allow tht usage ...so i used cin.getline